"So, why would we possibly want to go there?" VS "So, why on earth would we want to go there?"
A person is telling about their visit to one of the the hottest place (the Death Valley) on Earth to experience how it is like there. So, before leaving for there, he is telling about how dangerous, risky it could be, also saying that some people who previously go there had perished due to lack of enough water.
He says:
So, why would we possibly want to go there? (see: 1:08-1:11)
The word "possibly" caught my attention, because the sentence still makes sense without it, too. So, I wonder why "possibly" was needed in the sentence.
I thought about it and looked it up, and I have realized that it makes the meaning of the sentence more surprising, shocking etc. However, it reminded me of another structure to create such an effect, which is "What/Why/How on earth ........?" For example:
Why on earth would we want to go there?
Is the effect created by "possibly" the same effect as "Why on earth....?"

Why would [subject] possibly want [unlikely thing]? is used quite often, and in most cases it's equivalent to Why on earth would [subject] want [unlikely thing]? But we're much more likely to use Why + ever...

...which reflects the well-established utterance "Whyever not?" used if someone expresses doubts about something you've proposed. My Google spellchecker doesn't like one-word whyever, but the full Oxford English Dictionary lists it from 1924...

whyever (definition 2, 1924–, interrogative)
An emphatic extension of why, implying perplexity or surprise (colloquial; frequently written as two words).
Whyever or Why ever did you do that?


Yes; you could think of it as "how could it be possible that we would want to go there?" That is, it's rhetorically suggesting a distinction between reality and fantasy, that wanting to go there is "impossible" as a reality. Similarly, "how on earth" could be understood as rhetorically trying to limit the discussion to "earthly" reality.
